# Define different :root for child component

Tags: css, sass

I have an html page with an header navbar and content. Both have their own `header.css` and `content.css` which define the `font-size` in the root.
The problem is that the second css overrides the first declaration and both components have the same font size in the root, which makes `rem` font sizing wrong for the header (in this case).

Is there a way to define two different roots or subroots?

(example)

```
html{
  font-size: 18px
}
#content:root{
  font-size: 11px
}
```

Comment: No, that is not possible. There _is_ only one root element.

Comment: A somewhat similar effect as you describe might be achievable using shadow DOM.